# Fastest way to replace string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I need to replace some string in a PHP code to make it look better. What would be the best way to go about that?

Comment: Replace it how? Please give an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Are you looking for the fastest way or the best way? They are very distinct questions.

Comment: see there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23605293/1291428

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual suspects would be [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: I don't believe it answers the question in regards to which one is the fastest unfortunately.

Comment: As the documentation mentions, `str_replace` is faster than `preg_replace` if you just need a simple string replacement. Also the question is vague enough that you cannot give a tailored answer. And in almost all cases the standard functions *are* sufficient and not a performance bottleneck.

Comment: For small parts strtr is faster.
I used strtr and str_replace simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace
```

Is a good way to go and uses regular expressions so you have flexibility as to how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a string in a lot of files once (e.g., you have something in your source code which you want to replace), sed might be the right tool for the job.

```
man sed
```

Comment: in php? how would you do it? I mean, assuming security is ON and `exec` is disabled...

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If str_replace works for your case, I think is faster and less memory consumer than preg_replace