# PHP: How to remove unnecessary dots in filename on file upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a script to upload files with PHP.
I already do some cleaning to remove ugly characters.

I would also like to to remove dots in the filename, EXCEPT for the last one, which indicates the file extension.

Anyone has an idea how I could do that.?

For example, how would you get

```
$filename = "water.fall_blue.sky.jpg";
$filename2 = "water.fall_blue.sky.jpeg";
```

to return this in both cases..?

```
water.fall_blue.sky
```

Comment: what if I want to upload archive.tar.gz?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php) and [Fastest Way to replace String in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869829/fastest-way-to-replace-string-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) to extract the file name (the "filename" array element is available since PHP 5.2); `str_replace()` all the dots out of it; and re-glue the file extension.

Comment: Great.! Learned something new today.! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how this can be done:

```
<?php
$string = "really.long.file.name.txt";
$lastDot = strrpos($string, ".");
$string = str_replace(".", "", substr($string, 0, $lastDot)) . substr($string, $lastDot);
?>
```

It converts filenames like so:

really.long.file.name.txt -> reallylongfilename.txt

Check here: [example](http://www.flyingpie.nl/dots.php)

[Edit] Updated script, dot position is cached now

Comment: would it not be better to substitute the `.` with a `_` ?

Comment: You should cache `strrpos($string, ".")` there not to run it twice.

Answer (score 1):

FILENAME = this/is(your,file.name.JPG

```
$basename=basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

$filename=pathinfo($basename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext=pathinfo($basename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//replace all these characters with an hyphen
$repar=array(".",","," ",";","'","\\","\"","/","(",")","?");

$repairedfilename=str_replace($repar,"-",$filename);
$cleanfilename=$repairedfilename.".".strtolower($ext);
```

RESULT = this-is-your-file-name.jpg