# How create custom variables inside HTML

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to replace string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869829/fastest-way-to-replace-string-in-php)

I was trying to manage custom variables that i have made inside my html tags like:

```
<title>{myTitle}</title>
```

now how can i replace those custom variables "{...}" by using PHP?
i saw most of the template engines are able to do that.

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you just use a template engine, then?

Comment: Study the Smarty  architecture. You will get your answer there.

Comment: *(reference)* [String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: @Gordon: dear gordon, i don't load my pages from another one, so i'm not able to use str_replace

Comment: @Tomalak i want to do it my self (improving my knowledge)

Comment: @Shadow you should do more research then. Every template engine loads the template in order to replace the template vars. And `str_replace` and `preg_replace` are *the* functions to replace strings in PHP. If you define the values for the template vars in the template itself, then simply use `<?php echo $myTitle ?>`.

Comment: @Shadow Walker - PHP only processes the parts of files inside `<? ... ?>` tags. To do anything else, you will have to load the file from inside PHP and do your own replacements. That's how template engines work, and you could do a lot worse than look at their source for more detail

Comment: @Gorder thank you, yes, i had that in my mind, but i wanted to make sure there are no other ways to do that

Comment: This is a very good question! I too, needed to make a very basic template script. This question gave me a push and I got my script :)

Comment: @Kalle yeah, that was in my mind for month :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the very simple version of a template engine. Obviously you need to put that in a class with more features :)

**Display page**

```
<?php

define(TEMPLATES_LOCATION, 'templates/');

function TemplateFunction ($template, $replaces) {
    $template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATES_LOCATION . $template);
    if (is_array($replaces)) {
        foreach($replaces as $replacekey => $replacevalue){
            $template = str_replace('{$' . $replacekey . '}', $replacevalue, $template);
        }
    }
    return $template;
}

$keys = array(
    'TITLE' => 'This is page title',
    'HEADER' => 'This is some header'
);

echo TemplateFunction('body.tpl', $keys);


?>
```

**Template file** (Located at templates/body.tpl)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{$TITLE}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{$HEADER}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**(EDIT) Single file version**

```
<?php

define(TEMPLATES_LOCATION, '');

function TemplateFunction ($template, $replaces) {
    // $template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATES_LOCATION . $template);
    if (is_array($replaces)) {
        foreach($replaces as $replacekey => $replacevalue){
            $template = str_replace('{$' . $replacekey . '}', $replacevalue, $template);
        }
    }
    return $template;
}

$keys = array(
    'TITLE' => 'This is page title',
    'HEADER' => 'This is some header'
);

$template = '<html>
<head>
    <title>{$TITLE}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{$HEADER}</h1>
</body>
</html>';

echo TemplateFunction($template, $keys);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Kalle, but what if i want both html and php codes be in same page?

Comment: No problem. Well, how about this? You can manipulate this a little, but technically the TemplateFunction must be called after, everything else is figured out and set.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is already a basic templating environment, or you can use tools like Smarty for more capabilities. But with PHP itself, you can simply include standard variables:

`<title><?= $myTitle ?></title>`

Comment: thank you, it's many years I'm doing like that, now i want to do it inside html without using php directly

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = new array();
$arr["test"] = "hello";
$arr["foo"] = "world"

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   $yourTemplateAsString = str_replace("{".$key."}", $value, $yourTemplateAsString);
}
```

simple solution ... sure you could do some fancy stuff with regular expressions and add foreach and stuff like this.

Comment: Yeah i know sample above, thanks you very much, the only thing I'm stuck is, what if i want my php code and html be in one page, how can i prevent it to be shown before i replace my variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a syntax like that you can use [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/intro.html), it's a template engine for php.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but I'm searching for a solution to do it my self, i don't want to use engines

Comment: Then you'll need something like [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). BTW Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm just curious, i want to learn that :)